# Block scoping in JavaScript for loops?

Tags: javascript

Why does this code print 6 with VAR but "i" and the incremented for loop value with LET?

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log("i " + i);
    }, i * 1000)
}
```

Comment: That's just how the behavior of `let` is defined.

Comment: The variable defined by `var` is hoisted to the top, in this case (since you don't have it inside a function) it becomes a global variable. Therefore the function that is called by setTimeout access the global variable when it is executed. Since it executes long after the for-loop was finished, it will always return the latest value, in this case 6.

Answer (score 0):

Variables defined as `var` is automatically moved to the top.

Even if you define it like this:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log("i " + i);
    }, i * 1000)
}
```

it is used as if you had written

```
var i;

for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log("i " + i);
    }, i * 1000)
}
```

Since i is now like a global variable, the for-loop executes and leaves the variable with value 6. When the function is called by setTimeout in the future, the value is 6 for all calls.

You can read more about [let](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) and [var](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var).

Answer (score 0):

The difference between `var` and `let` is the scope:

[`var` scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var):

> Declared variables are constrained in the execution context in which they are declared. Undeclared variables are always global.

[`let` scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let):

> Variables declared by let have as their scope the block in which they are defined, as well as in any contained sub-blocks.

When you run your example with `var`, the loop will execute quickly and end before the `setTimeout()` functions starts executing, and when they execute, they get the current value of the `i` variable which is 6.

When you run your example with `let`, the loop will also execute quickly and end before the `setTimeout()` functions starts executing. However this time because the `i` variable is scoped to the loop, it will keep each value in the context memory for each `setTimeout()` function call.

To achieve the same effect with 'var', you can create a different context using a closure to preserve the value, like what `let` does:

```js
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
  (function(i) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log("i " + i);
    }, i * 1000);
  })(i);
}
```